# Asp button don't postback if

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, onclick

I have a login box, made with jquery with text boxes and then an asp:button, that validates and makes the sessions, like in the code.

I have made that a label appears when the username and password is wrong and you click the asp:button, but because of the post back the login box disappears.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Connectons etc...
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email = @email AND password = @pass";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pass", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password.Text;
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        Session["user_id"] = reader["user_id"];
        Session["username"] = reader["Username"];
        Session["name"] = reader["Name"];
        Session["password"] = reader["Password"];
        Session["LoggedIn"] = true;
        Session["role"] = reader["Role_id"];
        if (Convert.ToInt32(reader["Role_id"]) == 1)
        {
   Response.Redirect("Admin/default.aspx");
        }

        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }

    }

    else
    {

        Label1.Text = "Login is wrong";

    }

    conn.Close();


}
```

How do i make the button not post back if the login is wrong?

```
        <a id="modal_trigger" href="#modal" class="btn btn-default">Log ind</a>

    <div id="modal" class="popupContainer" style="display: none;"> </div>

         $("#modal_trigger").leanModal({
        top: 100,
        overlay: 0.6,
        closeButton: ".modal_close"
    });
```

Comment: Since you're validating the login on the server, it would be impossible for you to prevent a postback (since the user validation doesn't occur until the button is clicked). Do you mean you want to disable the login button for future attempts if the first login is incorrect?

Comment: Also - you want to wrap your conn (and your com) in a USING if you are going to redirect before you close it.

Comment: If you mean you don't want to allow postback if the username or password field is empty, then you use control validators. Just clarify what you wnt and we'll help

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I just wish i knew how to make the jquery pop up box stay.

Comment: How is it rendered in the first place?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a postback condition attached to your login rendering (like if(!isPostBack(renderLogin())? If that is the case, just re-call the method to render the loginbox if the login is incorrect.

Comment: I don't have that, but it makes sense to like call the login box if the login is wrong, after the site reloads.

Comment: Yes - something is making the login box appear. Whether that's in JavaScript or C# - that's what you need to find and re-create if the login is wrong

Comment: Is it possible to "click on a button" in c#?

Comment: Yes you do have that -- where is the jquery code to create the box in the first place?

Comment: If you share that I can help you. It's a DIV or a method or code - the box doesn't just appear without something telling it to.

Comment: I have written the codes in my question.

Comment: Ok see my answer and let meknow if that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not in the postback, it's in the fact that you're using a predefined login box that is only rendered when the page is not in postback state. Essentially, the rendering code is assuming that every login will be successful.

To fix this, you need to find where/when/how the predefined login "box" is created, and add the line to recreate it right after your "login incorrect" text.

In this manner, the login "box" will re-appear if the first attempt failed.

```
 if (Convert.ToInt32(reader["Role_id"]) == 1)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Admin/default.aspx");
    }

    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }

}

else
{

    reDraw = true;
}

//this has page scope (outside all methods)
bool reDraw = false;

private void reDrawLogin(){
      Label1.Text = "Login is wrong";
    //re-render login box to allow for another try
    string myScript = "\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"Javascript\" id=\"EventScriptBlock\">\n";
    myScript += "style="display: block;visibility:visible"> 
    myScript += "\n\n </script>";
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myKey", myScript, false);
 }

 //in your page_load, add:

 if(isPostBack){
    if(reDraw){
       reDrawLogin();
       reDraw=false;
    }
 }
```

and don't foret the USING in your CONN and COM!!! Good luck.

Comment: It doesn't work. The box still disappear. But thanks, now i at least know what to find out.

Comment: It's probably being called too soon. I made changes to my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In button property add AutoPostBack=False

Note: as per your question it is not clear what you want to achieve but as you have asked how to add autopostback to false , so i gave the above answer.
If you want to prevent postback if the login is incorrect then it is not possible because the validation of credential of user happen only after the button is clicked.

Comment: *as per your question it is not clear* then make sure you should make it clear first using comments

Answer (score 1):

A Postback needs to be called to reach the code you have up there. You could use some ajax to query your db onClick and cause a postback when successful I believe. I don't have an example. sorry.

Comment: Anyone who has that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117054/how-to-authenticate-username-password-in-jquery-with-asp-net The second answer is a great example.

Comment: but you will need to understand how to send and receive json through a post or a get